# Null Response fron "http" API using retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to connect APIs. It is working fine when fetching data from https API but getting response "Null" and error body response "okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@174390c" when fetching data from http API.

Here is the Retrofit client class:

```
   public static Retrofit getSClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Here is the Apiservice Class:

```
  @GET("Mobile/OperatorFetch?")
  Call<String>getOperatorDetails(@Query("apimember_id")String apiMemberId,
                                      @Query("api_password")String apiPassword,
                                      @Query("Mobileno")String mobileNumber);
```

Here is the ApiUtils Class:

```
public static ApiService getSApiService(){
    return RetrofitClient.getSClient(PLAN_URL).create(ApiService.class);
}
```

Here is my network request method from Repository class:

```
    private void fetchOperator(String apiId, String apiPassword, String mobile) {

    ApiService apiService = ApiUtills.getSApiService();
    apiService.getOperatorDetails(apiId, apiPassword, mobile)
            .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                        Log.e(TAG,"Operator fetch successful: " + response.body().toString());

                    }else {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Operator fetch failed: " + response.errorBody().toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.e(TAG,"Fetch operator failed" + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

Getting response from Post Man

[image: API is working fine in Postman]

Comment: Could you please show the base URL and also please you getting from Retrofit

Comment: @AlphaOne  http://planapi.in/api/ this is my base URL and I'm getting null response from retrofit

Comment: You need to add / before mobile in your get request, like `@GET("/Mobile/OperatorFetch?")`

Comment: @AlphaOne tried already. It doesn't solved the problem. I think I'm getting this error bcoz this api is associated with http and not https

Comment: Yes, Might be, have you added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @AlphaOne Yes I've added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest file and I also added networkconfigation file to support device running lower than api 23